# how to compare a pair of words in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

I have 2 columns like this:

```
col     count
(A,B)    19
(C,D)    18
(E,F)    10
(B,A)    9
(D,C)    80
```

I want this:

for each pair `(pair1,pair2)` in `col` if `(pair2,pair1)` exist, select one with higher `count`

`output`:

```
col     count
(A,B)    19
(E,F)    10
(D,C)    80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for get maximal `count` index values grouping by sorted and converted lists to tuples:

```
g = df['col'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))
df = df.loc[df.groupby(g)['count'].idxmax()]
print (df)
      col  count
0  (A, B)     19
4  (D, C)     80
2  (E, F)     10
```

Another idea is use `np.sort` for sorting values and pass first and second 1d array:

```
g = np.sort(df['col'].tolist(), axis=1)
df = df.loc[df.groupby([g[:, 0], g[:, 1]])['count'].idxmax()]
print (df)
      col  count
0  (A, B)     19
4  (D, C)     80
2  (E, F)     10
```

EDIT:

Another solution if input values are tuples:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df['col'].tolist(), axis=1), 
                   index=df.index, 
                   columns=['key1','key2'])
        .join(df)
        .sort_values(['key1','key2','count'])
        .drop_duplicates(['key1','key2'], keep='last')
        .drop(['key1','key2'], axis=1))
print (df)
      col  count
3  (B, A)     19
1  (C, D)     80
2  (E, F)     10
```

If there are joioned strings by `,`:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df['col'].str.split(',').tolist(), axis=1), 
                   index=df.index, 
                   columns=['key1','key2'])
        .join(df)
        .sort_values(['key1','key2','count'])
        .drop_duplicates(['key1','key2'], keep='last')
        .drop(['key1','key2'], axis=1)
        )
print (df)
   col  count
0  A,B     19
4  D,C     80
2  E,F     10
```

Comment: could you add some explanation/

Comment: which one is faster for big data?

Comment: @elham - I think second one.

Comment: If I don't have brackets `(` this method still works?

Comment: @elham - Then need `df['col'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x.split(','))))`

Comment: also if I have words instead of `A`, `B`. like `summer, winter`

Comment: @elham - If there are strings like `summer, winter` use `df['col'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x.split(','))))` or split by commae wit hspace like `, ` like `df['col'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x.split(', '))))`

Comment: your code is working very well on my small df, but it doesn't work on the large one. I am so surprised . can't figure out why. do you have any idea?

Comment: @elham - are data types same? there are tuples in both DataFrames?

Comment: even I slice some part of the big data and tried it and it worked

Comment: @elham - So it means if use first 10k rows it working, but if use 100k rows it failed?

Comment: @elham - Not idea, added new solution. I hope working well in huge data

Comment: error:`AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1`